# Jquery.text() and .html fail after DOM change on Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am using Jquery to change the content of an iframe on a web page using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html1 = $('#result iframe').text();
    console.log('Before');
    console.log(html1)
    $('#result iframe').contents().find('body').append('<p>hello</p>');
    var html2 = $('#result iframe').text();
    console.log('After');
    console.log(html2)
});

 </script>
    <div id="result">
        <iframe id="result">
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I can see a change on the actual webpage but the changes don't appear on the log. I tried using the .html() function but I have the same problem. I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AbE89/

I have found similar issues on stackoverflow but this was mostly an outdated browser issue and I am using the latest chrome. I also tried with the latest version of Firefox and still no luck. Has anybody run into the same problem?

Comment: Try `console.log($('#result iframe').contents().find('html').html())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html1 = $('#result iframe').contents().find('html').html();
    console.log('Before');
    console.log(html1)
    $('#result iframe').contents().find('body').append('<p>hello</p>');
    var html2 = $('#result iframe').contents().find('html').html();
    console.log('After');
    console.log(html2)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7tjpC/)

If you want the html to include the `<html>` element also then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html1 = $('#result iframe').contents().find('html').get(0).outerHTML;
    console.log('Before');
    console.log(html1)
    $('#result iframe').contents().find('body').append('<p>hello</p>');
    var html2 = $('#result iframe').contents().find('html').get(0).outerHTML;
    console.log('After');
    console.log(html2)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QAjUC/)